# Regex to match string between brackets

Tags: regex, bash

I have a regex that properly returns this:

```
[a1]
[b892jklas]
[klaj218349]
[alllasd]
```

But I just want to match and return:

```
a1
b892jklas
klaj218349
alllasd
```

I'm using the following command

```
cmd | grep -i -o -E '\[[[:alnum:]]\]'
```

But I don't know how to exclude the brackets from the result.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Po '(<=\[)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\])'
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

`tr -d '[]'` also works (Thanks @1_CR for the comment)

ORIGINAL POST:

`... | tr -s "[" "" | tr -s "]" ""` is the simplest solution. You can also used `sed`...

Comment: Why not ` tr -d '[]'`?

Answer (score 1):

If GNU grep is an option (also this should have been compiled against a recent version of libpcre.so for `\K` to work)

```
grep -oP '\[[[:space:]]*\K[[:alnum:]]+(?=[[:space:]]*\])'
```